After installing Ubuntu 24.04, Ubuntu shows two displays but I only have one
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and it detects two monitors, one of which is a ghost, non-existing one. I have an old PC Lenovo ThinkCentre M92P, with 20 GB of RAM and a NVidia GT710 video Card. I didn't have this problem before when using Ubuntu 22.04.
Even though there is at least one question here on how to get rid of this second ghost monitor, those questions date back to several years ago.
My knowledge in Linux is limited and I would like, if possible, a step by step guidance to solve this annoying problem.
Following other posts, I was able to run the xrandr -q command. Below is its output:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm panning 3840x1080+0+0
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 144.00   119.98    99.93  
   1440x900     119.85  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02    60.02  
   1024x768     119.99    75.03    60.00  
   800x600      119.97    75.00    60.32  
   640x480      120.01    75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +

I believe that DVI-D-0 is where my real BENQ monitor is connected to and None-1-1 is the ghost one.
I would really appreciate your help to solve this issue.

This https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509661/could-not-switch-the-monitor-configuration-on-none-1-1-connected-output/1514074#1514074 or this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516532/how-do-disable-get-rid-of-prime-display take what works for you

Amar, thanks a lot, my man! I added the script to the X11 config file you recommended and that evil ghost display was gone. Thanks a lot!
